# Working text-overflow in android browser (4.4.2)?

Tags: android, css

I have a problem with a web application. I have these CSS rules to make sure that if text is overflowing it will be shown with three dots. It works perfectly on all browsers that I have tested(desktop and mobile). One big except is android stock browser and more importantly only RTL mode (I have attached an image of the rendered output).

`display: inline-block;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;`

The output should be Option 1, Option 2 and so on. There is enough space to fit this small text there but is cut off.

I have tried to use text-rendering: optimizeLegibility option and it helps in some cases but not all.

Does any one have any ideas what might be a solution for this problem?

Thank you for your time!

[image: Android stock browser]